# Ubuntu Desktop & VMWare VSphere client?

Tags: virtualization, vmware

Wondering ubuntu/debian community
How do you manage your VMware VCenter from Ubuntu Desktop (18.04)?

New VSphere Client (HTML5) is not an option, old VSphere web client is Flash, and I'm unable to run Vsphere Desktop Client (5.5 & 6.0) in Wine

Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you say that: "New VSphere Client (HTML5) is not an option"?

Comment: cuz our VCenters are outdated...

Comment: Well, you could do what most admins do and run Windows (in a VM)...

Comment: Yeah... I know... and that works... But that's exactly what I'd like to avoid

Comment: Well, then it's time to upgrade vCenter...

Comment: @dgoosens if your systems are vCenter managed then you need to update vCenter to get newer functionality.  No way around that unfortunately.